# Transform local coordinates to WGS84 and back in C#

Tags: c#, gis

Some people working on a the construction site use a local custom coordinate system. I have been given a proj4 string like this:

***+proj=omerc +lat_0=46.325454996 +lonc=7.99050231 +alpha=60.4026421358 +gamma=90 +k=1 +x_0=350 +y_0=200 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs***

And x,y coordinates like this **429.079425606807, 261.126436507318**

And I need to convert their coordinates into WGS84 and back

I tried to use the [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial) to make the transformation. Any other libraries in C# can be accepted.

```
 string proj4_custom = "+proj=omerc +lat_0=46.325454996 +lonc=7.99050231 +alpha=60.4026421358 +gamma=90 +k=1 +x_0=350 +y_0=200 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs";

 DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo src = DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String(proj4_custom);
 int googleEPSGCode = 4326;
 DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo trg = DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(googleEPSGCode);

 double[] xy = new[] { 429.079425606807, 261.126436507318 };
 double[] z = new[] { 0d };
 DotSpatial.Projections.Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xy, z, src, trg, 0, 1);
```

But the result in xy is not correct, on the map it's about 50 to 100 meters away. I should have a result really close to this correct result

```
Local coordinates: 429.07942560 261.1264365
WGS84: 7.99100318 46.326284519
```

What am I doing wrong?? If the problem is related to a bug in the libraries, what other libraries can I use that do it correctly?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used GDAL, the nuget package MaxRev.Gdal.WindowsRuntime.Minimal.

```
string proj = "+proj=omerc +lat_0=46.325454996 +lonc=7.99050231+alpha=60.4026421358 +gamma=90 +k=1 +x_0=350 +y_0=200 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs";  
SpatialReference local = new SpatialReference("");
local.ImportFromProj4(proj);
    
SpatialReference wgs84Reference = new SpatialReference("");
wgs84Reference.ImportFromProj4("+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +no_defs");
    
CoordinateTransformation coordinateTransform = new CoordinateTransformation(wgs84Reference, local);
double[] xy = new[] { lon, lat };
double[] z = new[] { alt };
coordinateTransform.TransformPoint(xy);
lon = xy[0];
lat = xy[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Original source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70089/lambert93-to-wgs84-ign-algorithms-longitude-problem

A java class I quickly ported to C#

```
public class Lambert93
{
    private const double M_PI_2 = Math.PI / 2.0;
    private const double DEFAULT_EPS = 1e-10;
    private const double E_WGS84 = 0.08181919106;
    private const double E2 = E_WGS84 / 2.0;
    private const double LON_MERID_IERS = 3.0 * Math.PI / 180.0;
    private const double N = 0.7256077650;
    private const double C = 11_754_255.426;
    private const double XS = 700_000.000;
    private const double YS = 12_655_612.050;

    public static (double latitude, double longitude) ToLatLon(double x, double y)
    {
        double dX = x - XS;
        double dY = y - YS;
        double R = Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
        double gamma = Math.Atan(dX / -dY);
        double latIso = -1 / N * Math.Log(Math.Abs(R / C));
        var longitude = ToDegrees(LON_MERID_IERS + gamma / N);
        var latitude = ToDegrees(LatitudeFromLatitudeISO(latIso));

        return (latitude, longitude);
    }

    static double ToDegrees(double radians) => radians * 180f / Math.PI;

    static double LatitudeFromLatitudeISO(double latISo)
    {
        double phi0 = 2 * Math.Atan(Math.Exp(latISo)) - M_PI_2;
        double phiI = 2
           * Math.Atan(Math.Pow((1 + E_WGS84 * Math.Sin(phi0)) /
                       (1 - E_WGS84 * Math.Sin(phi0)), E2) * Math.Exp(latISo))
           - M_PI_2;
        double delta = Math.Abs(phiI - phi0);
        while (delta > DEFAULT_EPS)
        {
            phi0 = phiI;
            phiI =
               2 * Math.Atan(Math.Pow(
                     (1 + E_WGS84 * Math.Sin(phi0)) /
                     (1 - E_WGS84 * Math.Sin(phi0)), E2)
                  * Math.Exp(latISo)) - M_PI_2;
            delta = Math.Abs(phiI - phi0);
        }
        return phiI;
    }
}
```